# Traverse multiple XML documents to find particular attributes using R

Tags: r

I have a series of several thousand URLs that link to prescription drug labels and am trying to figure out how many have a patient package insert.  I am attempting to do this by reading in the URLs within a data frame, then using the XML package to parse the html, and ultimately use grep to perform my search for the string "Patient Package Insert".  Ultimately, I am trying to count the number of prescription drug labels with a patient package insert.

I've put together a toy example below:

```
library(XML)
urls <- c("http://dailymed.nlm.nih.gov/dailymed/lookup.cfm?setid=a002b40c-097d-47a5-957f-7a7b1807af7f",
         "http://dailymed.nlm.nih.gov/dailymed/lookup.cfm?setid=1842bb9f-60ab-4af9-95a4-1cfc3645ee6b", 
         "http://dailymed.nlm.nih.gov/dailymed/lookup.cfm?ndc=50419-758&start=1&labeltype=all")

Data <- data.frame(urls)
Data$insert <- lapply(Data$urls, function(x) {
   y <- xmlToList(htmlParse(x))
   y.flat <- unlist(y, recursive = TRUE)
   length(grep("Patient Package Insert", c(y.flat,names(y.flat))))
})

Data <- as.data.frame(lapply(Data, unlist))
count(Data$insert)
```

At the moment this is picking up the links for "Patient Package Insert" that are included in each of these webpages, however only some of them are active. For sake of example, the second and third URLs included in the toy example above do not feature an active link (it is grayed out) to the "Patient Package Insert", which I would like to NOT count in my final tabulation.  Ideally, I would like to only flag the first link, which includes a functional "Patient Package Insert" link.  Does anyone know how best to do this in R?  If so, I would greatly appreciate any and all help.

Many thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like the following:

```
xData <- lapply(Data$urls, htmlParse)
ppiData <- lapply(xData, FUN = xpathApply, path = "/descendant-or-self::*[contains(@title, 'Patient Package Insert')]", fun = xmlAttrs)
ppiData

[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
                   title                     href                    class 
"Patient Package Insert"            "#nlm42230-3"            "nlmlinktrue" 


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
                   title                     href                    class 
"Patient Package Insert"            "#nlm42230-3"           "nlmlinkfalse" 


[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
                   title                     href                    class 
"Patient Package Insert"            "#nlm42230-3"           "nlmlinkfalse"
```

On this simple example you could process to a dataframe:

```
ppiData <- lapply(ppiData, function(x){data.frame(as.list(x[[1]]))})
ppiData <- do.call(rbind, ppiData)

> ppiData
                   title        href        class
1 Patient Package Insert #nlm42230-3  nlmlinktrue
2 Patient Package Insert #nlm42230-3 nlmlinkfalse
3 Patient Package Insert #nlm42230-3 nlmlinkfalse
```

with your real data set the 2nd step maybe a bit more involved with multiple entries possible etc.

Comment: Perfect!  This worked brilliantly -- I can't begin to thank you enough.

Comment: if this answers your question please consider marking the question as answered. http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the HTML value that is returned, rather than just the greppish value you can find:

```
$body$div$div$fieldset$div$ul$li$a$.attrs
                   title                     href                    class 
"Patient Package Insert"            "#nlm42230-3"           "nlmlinkfalse"
```

... but the item above it has a class value of "nlmlinktrue". So maybe you will need to go through all the unfortunately unnamed `$body$div$div$fieldset$div$ul$li$a$.text` nodes to find the "Patient Package Insert" item and then see what its `$body$div$div$fieldset$div$ul$li$a$.attrs` class value is.

When I do that by hand on the third item I get:

```
Data$insert[[3]]$body[14]$div[12]$div[2]$fieldset[3]$div[2]$ul[27]$li[2]

$a
$a$text
[1] "Patient Package Insert"

$a$.attrs
                   title                     href                    class 
"Patient Package Insert"            "#nlm42230-3"           "nlmlinkfalse"
```

To do it by hand you can grep to find the next node that contains "Package Insert"

```
> head(sapply( Data$insert[[3]], FUN=grep, patt="Package Insert" ))
$head
integer(0)

$body
[1] 14

$.attrs
integer(0)

> head(sapply( Data$insert[[3]]$body[14], FUN=grep, patt="Package Insert" ))
div 
 12 
>
```

Comment: Nice response -- thanks.  This doesn't appear as though it would an easy process to automate, does it?  I have a couple thousand of these links to go through, which makes me a bit reluctant to leap into this manually.

Comment: I don't really know. It might be easy for someone like Martin Morgan or John Colby. I've been looking at SO postings with various combinations of:  `html/xml parse traverse attributes` ... still without success but I wouldn't be surprised if there were a method to find all the `li` nodes with a title attribute of "Patient Package Insert". Some sort of wizardly incantation with a function name similar to `xpathApply` might exist.

Comment: Hahaha.  Thanks for the prompt, witty, and helpful reply.